# how to load html page variable into python variable using the web address

Tags: javascript, python, html, web

I found a guide here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html 
but the function *HTMLParser.feed(data)* uses data as the html itself.

There is a way to do similar feed but only with the web address ?
something like this ... 
*HTMLParser.feed("www.a.com")*   ?

Generally, i want to take a variable from different web pages and load it into python variable with python script and compere between them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
page_data = f.read()

# do stuff with html
HTMLParser.feed(page_data)

f.close()
```

This will return the raw html from the page. You can then parse it and find whatever you want. Not sure if there is a faster solution.

Comment: The Python 2 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#high-level-interface) has a warning the the `urllib.urlopen()` function has been "Deprecated since version 2.6: The `urlopen()` function has been removed in Python 3 in favor of `urllib2.urlopen()`" — here's the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#module-urllib2) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe
[python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)?

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://github.com/")
r.content
```

Later if you want to parse the content you can use [lxml](http://lxml.de/)